# Maven fail deploy war - Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/]

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, deployment

I just finished my Java app and I'm trying to deploy it to Tomcat 7.
The problem is that starting run war file causes errors:

FAIL - Application at context path /tradesystem-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/tradesystem-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]

I have read many articles and I still didn't solve that.

when I'm write in console 'java -version' it shows v11, which fits with version of compiler (settings > compiler > java compiler > target byte code of project

I've read also, that errors can be caused of bad structure of target folder (someone wrote, that folder 'classes' in target/classes should be deletted but it didn't help.

My sugestion is that I missing some obvious configuration in pom.xml or something like that, but I really don't want to mess up my project, so I've decided to ask you guys.
The screenshot shows structure of my project.
[image: The screenshot shows structure of my project]

Please keep in mind that's my first deploy ever and the bug for most could be obvious.

Comment: Is that the complete exception you are showing?  Or are there more exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by following that article:

https://dzone.com/articles/deploy-spring-boot-apps-from-jar-to-war

I just skip section **2. Update your Main class to extends SpringBootServletInitializer**

Topic can be closed.